# Raycast, in Unity 3d does not detect all obstacles

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, raycasting

I'm trying to make a very simple race game with spheres, however, I face many problems.

First of all, I'm trying to make a very simple AI system for opponents.

The problem I have here is that I want opponents to detect obstacles and avoid them using Raycast but only a certain type of obstacle , a simple cube is detected.

I've created a simple sphere as opponent and wrote a script so it can move and detect obstacles 
Here is update function:

```
void FixedUpdate()
{
    transform.Translate(Vector3.forward * Time.deltaTime * speed);

    if (Physics.Raycast(transform.position, transform.forward, 100.0f))
        print("There is something in front of the object!");

}
```

The message is printed only when there is a cube forward and it does not detect any other obstacles. What can be so wrong? Also, is there any idea how to move left or right when opponent raycast an obstacle?

[obstacle that is detected](https://i.stack.imgur.com/f4j2F.png)

[hierarchy](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1hnMI.png)

[cube01 that is child of obstacle2 that is not detected](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JRiAz.png)

Comment: No idea, can't help you if you don't tell us about your hierchy and specifically the different between the objects it does detect and the objects it doesnt detect.

Comment: *"Also, is there any idea how to move left or right when opponent raycast an obstacle?"* You also have to do raycast to `transform.right` and `-transform.right`. In fact, you should be using `NavMesh` for this. Start with [this](https://unity3d.com/learn/tutorials/topics/navigation/navigation-overview?playlist=17105) tutorial.

Comment: @Eddge I've added some screenshots. Are they enough?

Comment: @Programmer Thanks !!!

Comment: Try making their x and y the same? Based off of your code you are not turning (or strafing), so it is possible your ray cast is missing,  you can also use Debug.DrawLine in your normal update to see where the raycast is.  

https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Debug.DrawLine.html

Comment: @Eddge what do u mean make x and y the same ? I mean where? Sorry , I'm a beginner and I don't understand that much..

Comment: @MariaKodel in your screenshots they have a transform with a position set the x and y to like 4 and 0.5

Comment: @Eddge It's not the position , I've tried this before..

Comment: Are there colliders on all targets?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Unity Physics Best Practices (As in https://unity3d.com/pt/learn/tutorials/topics/physics/physics-best-practices) recommends that we don't use Raycasts in FixedUpdate, as it is heavy to process and may not always work.

There is also some tips about Matrix Layers that will help you improve performance and avoid such bugs.

Good luck!

Answer (score 1):

Only collider components are detected using raycast, make sure you have an appropriate collider (size of the collider does not necesarily match size of the mesh that gets rendered).  Normally also layers on which objects are are important but syntax you are using is not checking for layer mask anyway

Answer (score 0):

You can use Debug.DrawLine() or Debug.DrawLine() to debug the line and see if it cross the obstacles or not.
Here is the documentation for them 
[DrawRay](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Debug.DrawRay.html)
[DrawLine](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Debug.DrawLine.html)
For moving right and left I think you can add something like this

```
void FixedUpdate()
{
    Vector3 dir = Vector3.forward * Time.deltaTime * speed;
    if (Physics.Raycast(transform.position, transform.forward, 100.0f))
    {
        print("There is something in front of the object!");
        dir += Vector3.Right * horizontalSpeed * Time.deltaTime;
    }
}
```

You might also consider ray casting two rays to detect the direction to lean to if it will be the left or the right.